# Where to begin with British, French, and Belgian ancestry?

Tags: united-kingdom, france, belgium, getting-started

I have just recently began my search to find my family history. I traced back using the family tree app my great, great, great great Grandfather; Benoit (Benedict) Spennewyn, but cannot seem to get further than this.

How do I find where he lived to search local records?

I do know I have strong British, French, and Belgian ancestry.

Comment: Your question is very broad.  Which app?  What has it given you? How do you know it is correct?  Why do you think Ancestry would help?  It would help if you gave more detail.

Comment: How much an Ancestry.com membership will help you is a matter of opinion which may lead to votes for the closure of your question.  I think you should focus your question on finding the birth family of Benoit (Benedict) Spennewyn.  What do you already know about him?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! Please take a look at the [help] especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) See https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/6696/1006 for tips on how to evaluate the holdings of a website before you pay for it. Hints can be helpful but they also rob us of the opportunity to learn search strategies and gain skill in evaluating records and record collections for ourselves. Your question could be improved by teling us which records you have already looked at.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment that your question is very broad.  Searching records in France, Belgium, and England all require different knowledge.  Take a look at other questions on the site about immigrant ancestors to see if any of the methodology helps you. You can edit your question at any time to make it more specific.  Also see https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/3625/1006

Answer (score 1):

The [Geneanet](https://www.geneanet.org/) site could be of help, it's very popular in France.

I've found 2 occurences of Benoit (Benedict) Spennewyn :

- https://gw.geneanet.org/mike1960?n=spennewyn&oc=&p=benoit+benedict
- https://www.stehelene.org/cgi-bin/lh/stehelene-search.pl?indexdata=indexmedf&title=1&table=medf&qprenom=Beno%EEt&qnom=SPENNEWYN